# Debezium - MySQL Connector - Kinesis - Service Not Starting

Tags: apache-kafka, mysql-connector, amazon-kinesis, debezium

I am trying to get Debezium to send my CDC events to Kinesis and the service seems to start but there are errors, and it doesn't seem to be sending anything to Kinesis. I was following this setup guide on the Debezium site:

https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.2/operations/debezium-server.html

Here is my config file:

```
debezium.sink.type=kinesis
debezium.sink.kinesis.region=us-east-1
debezium.source.connector.class=io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector
debezium.source.offset.storage.file.filename=data/offsets.dat
debezium.source.offset.flush.interval.ms=0
debezium.source.database.hostname=127.0.0.1
debezium.source.database.id=12345
debezium.source.database.port=3306
debezium.source.database.user=*****
debezium.source.database.password=******
debezium.source.database.dbname=inventory
debezium.source.database.server.name=127.0.0.1
debezium.source.schema.whitelist=inventory
```

When I run the server using `./run.sh`, the server seems to begin starting then I get an error:

```
2020-07-17 19:11:22,380 INFO  [io.deb.ser.BaseChangeConsumer] (main) Using 'io.debezium.server.BaseChangeConsumer$$Lambda$81/694452085@2abf4075' stream name mapper
2020-07-17 19:11:22,754 INFO  [io.deb.ser.kin.KinesisChangeConsumer] (main) Using default KinesisClient 'software.amazon.awssdk.services.kinesis.DefaultKinesisClient@5d5f10b2'
2020-07-17 19:11:22,755 INFO  [io.deb.ser.DebeziumServer] (main) Consumer 'io.debezium.server.kinesis.KinesisChangeConsumer' instantiated
2020-07-17 19:11:22,926 INFO  [org.apa.kaf.con.jso.JsonConverterConfig] (main) JsonConverterConfig values:
    converter.type = key
    decimal.format = BASE64
    schemas.cache.size = 1000
    schemas.enable = true

2020-07-17 19:11:22,928 INFO  [org.apa.kaf.con.jso.JsonConverterConfig] (main) JsonConverterConfig values:
    converter.type = value
    decimal.format = BASE64
    schemas.cache.size = 1000
    schemas.enable = false

2020-07-17 19:11:22,936 INFO  [io.deb.emb.EmbeddedEngine$EmbeddedConfig] (main) EmbeddedConfig values:
    access.control.allow.methods =
    access.control.allow.origin =
    admin.listeners = null
    bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
    client.dns.lookup = default
    config.providers = []
    connector.client.config.override.policy = None
    header.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.SimpleHeaderConverter
    internal.key.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
    internal.value.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
    key.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
    listeners = null
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    offset.flush.interval.ms = 0
    offset.flush.timeout.ms = 5000
    offset.storage.file.filename = data/offsets.dat
    offset.storage.partitions = null
    offset.storage.replication.factor = null
    offset.storage.topic =
    plugin.path = null
    rest.advertised.host.name = null
    rest.advertised.listener = null
    rest.advertised.port = null
    rest.extension.classes = []
    rest.host.name = null
    rest.port = 8083
    ssl.client.auth = none
    task.shutdown.graceful.timeout.ms = 5000
    topic.tracking.allow.reset = true
    topic.tracking.enable = true
    value.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter

2020-07-17 19:11:22,937 INFO  [org.apa.kaf.con.run.WorkerConfig] (main) Worker configuration property 'internal.key.converter' is deprecated and may be removed in an upcoming release. The specified value 'org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter' matches the default, so this property can be safely removed from the worker configuration.
2020-07-17 19:11:22,937 INFO  [org.apa.kaf.con.run.WorkerConfig] (main) Worker configuration property 'internal.value.converter' is deprecated and may be removed in an upcoming release. The specified value 'org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter' matches the default, so this property can be safely removed from the worker configuration.
2020-07-17 19:11:22,939 INFO  [org.apa.kaf.con.jso.JsonConverterConfig] (main) JsonConverterConfig values:
    converter.type = key
    decimal.format = BASE64
    schemas.cache.size = 1000
    schemas.enable = true

2020-07-17 19:11:22,940 INFO  [org.apa.kaf.con.jso.JsonConverterConfig] (main) JsonConverterConfig values:
    converter.type = value
    decimal.format = BASE64
    schemas.cache.size = 1000
    schemas.enable = true

2020-07-17 19:11:22,942 INFO  [io.deb.ser.DebeziumServer] (main) Engine executor started
2020-07-17 19:11:22,948 INFO  [org.apa.kaf.con.sto.FileOffsetBackingStore] (pool-3-thread-1) Starting FileOffsetBackingStore with file data/offsets.dat
2020-07-17 19:11:22,989 INFO  [io.deb.con.com.BaseSourceTask] (pool-3-thread-1) Starting MySqlConnectorTask with configuration:
2020-07-17 19:11:22,990 INFO  [io.deb.con.com.BaseSourceTask] (pool-3-thread-1)    connector.class = io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector
2020-07-17 19:11:22,990 INFO  [io.deb.con.com.BaseSourceTask] (pool-3-thread-1)    offset.flush.interval.ms = 0
2020-07-17 19:11:22,990 INFO  [io.deb.con.com.BaseSourceTask] (pool-3-thread-1)    database.user = mysqluser
2020-07-17 19:11:22,990 INFO  [io.deb.con.com.BaseSourceTask] (pool-3-thread-1)    database.dbname = inventory
2020-07-17 19:11:22,990 INFO  [io.deb.con.com.BaseSourceTask] (pool-3-thread-1)    offset.storage.file.filename = data/offsets.dat
2020-07-17 19:11:22,990 INFO  [io.deb.con.com.BaseSourceTask] (pool-3-thread-1)    database.hostname = 127.0.0.1
2020-07-17 19:11:22,990 INFO  [io.deb.con.com.BaseSourceTask] (pool-3-thread-1)    database.id = 12345
2020-07-17 19:11:22,990 INFO  [io.deb.con.com.BaseSourceTask] (pool-3-thread-1)    database.password = ********
2020-07-17 19:11:22,990 INFO  [io.deb.con.com.BaseSourceTask] (pool-3-thread-1)    name = kinesis
2020-07-17 19:11:22,990 INFO  [io.deb.con.com.BaseSourceTask] (pool-3-thread-1)    database.server.name = 127.0.0.1
2020-07-17 19:11:22,990 INFO  [io.deb.con.com.BaseSourceTask] (pool-3-thread-1)    database.port = 3306
2020-07-17 19:11:22,991 INFO  [io.deb.con.com.BaseSourceTask] (pool-3-thread-1)    schema.whitelist = inventory
2020-07-17 19:11:23,063 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) debezium-server-dist 1.2.0.Final on JVM (powered by Quarkus 1.5.0.Final) started in 1.177s. Listening on: http://0.0.0.0:8080
2020-07-17 19:11:23,065 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Profile prod activated.
2020-07-17 19:11:23,065 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: [cdi, smallrye-health]
2020-07-17 19:11:23,276 ERROR [io.deb.rel.his.KafkaDatabaseHistory] (pool-3-thread-1) The 'database.history.kafka.topic' value is invalid: A value is required
2020-07-17 19:11:23,276 ERROR [io.deb.rel.his.KafkaDatabaseHistory] (pool-3-thread-1) The 'database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers' value is invalid: A value is required**
2020-07-17 19:11:23,277 INFO  [io.deb.con.com.BaseSourceTask] (pool-3-thread-1) Stopping down connector
2020-07-17 19:11:23,277 INFO  [io.deb.con.mys.MySqlConnectorTask] (pool-3-thread-1) Stopping MySQL connector task
2020-07-17 19:11:23,278 INFO  [org.apa.kaf.con.sto.FileOffsetBackingStore] (pool-3-thread-1) Stopped FileOffsetBackingStore
2020-07-17 19:11:23,278 INFO  [io.deb.ser.ConnectorLifecycle] (pool-3-thread-1) Connector completed: success = 'false', message = 'Unable to initialize and start connector's task class 'io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnectorTask' with config: {name=kinesis, connector.class=io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector, database.id=12345, schema.whitelist=inventory, database.port=3306, database.user=username, database.hostname=127.0.0.1, offset.storage.file.filename=data/offsets.dat, database.password=********, offset.flush.interval.ms=0, database.server.name=127.0.0.1, database.dbname=inventory}', error = '{}': org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Error configuring an instance of KafkaDatabaseHistory; check the logs for details
    at io.debezium.relational.history.KafkaDatabaseHistory.configure(KafkaDatabaseHistory.java:180)
    at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlSchema.<init>(MySqlSchema.java:139)
    at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlTaskContext.<init>(MySqlTaskContext.java:86)
    at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlTaskContext.<init>(MySqlTaskContext.java:52)
    at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnectorTask.createAndStartTaskContext(MySqlConnectorTask.java:357)
    at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnectorTask.start(MySqlConnectorTask.java:143)
    at io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask.start(BaseSourceTask.java:101)
    at io.debezium.embedded.EmbeddedEngine.run(EmbeddedEngine.java:756)
    at io.debezium.embedded.ConvertingEngineBuilder$2.run(ConvertingEngineBuilder.java:170)
    at io.debezium.server.DebeziumServer.lambda$start$1(DebeziumServer.java:133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

^C2020-07-18 00:00:44,245 INFO  [io.deb.ser.DebeziumServer] (main) Received request to stop the engine
2020-07-18 00:00:44,245 INFO  [io.deb.emb.EmbeddedEngine] (main) Stopping the embedded engine
2020-07-18 00:00:44,254 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) debezium-server-dist stopped in 0.028s
```

You can about 3/4 of the way down I get two errors related to:
io.deb.rel.his.KafkaDatabaseHistory

Using the Kinesis source I'm not sure why it's throwing these errors related to Kafka. Does anyone have any idea why this may be happening, or a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify [`debezium.source.database.history`](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.2/operations/debezium-server.html#debezium-source-database-history-class) property for the [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) connector. Its default value is `io.debezium.relational.history.KafkaDatabaseHistory`, so for non-Kafka deployments please set one of the following values:

- `io.debezium.relational.history.FileDatabaseHistory` (along with [`debezium.source.database.history.file.filename`](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.2/operations/debezium-server.html#debezium-source-database-history-file-filename) property);
- `io.debezium.relational.history.MemoryDatabaseHistory` for test environments.

Comment: Thank You! That did it. 

As a follow up is there a way to point the Kinesis connection at my localhost to use my localstack version for testing? I don't see any parameters that allow redirecting kinesis..

Comment: You’re welcome! If my answer was helpful, please accept and vote for it

Comment: I think you cannot do this, but you can try to ask in the Debezium chat - https://gitter.im/debezium/user